# RxJava2 changing type of Flowable object being returned by API

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

The DarkSkyAPI call returns `Forecast` object containing `WeeklyData` object that in turn contains `Array<DailyData>`.

My Repository class requires `Array<DailyData>` to cache and propagate the data to the Presenter.

Currently I am calling the API like this:
`Flowable<Forecast> response = service.getRxWeatherResponse(params...);`.

How can I unwrap this `Flowable<Forecast>` to extract `Flowable<Array<DailyData>>` to be returned to the Repository class?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to just use the map operator. http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#map-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it Chris, thanks! I've used the map operator as you advised. Final code returns `Observable` and looks like this:

```
return service.getRxWeatherResponse(API cal params...)
        .map(new Function<Forecast, List<DailyData>>() {
                 @Override
                 public List<DailyData> apply(Forecast forecast) throws Exception {
                     return forecast.getWeeklyData().getDailyData();
                 }
             });
```

Or simplified using lambda:

```
return service.getRxWeatherResponse(API cal params...)
        .map(forecast -> forecast.getWeeklyData().getDailyDataArray());
```